# Access RAID1 content from other Linux system of a dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, raid

I have prepared for a friend a little NAS made of Ubuntu Server 20.04 on an SSD and two HHD in RAID1.

The software RAID1 has been made during the Ubuntu installation, here some info about it:

```
$ fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 3.65 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD40EFRX-68N
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/sdb: 3.65 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Disk model: ST4000VN008-2DR1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/md1: 3.65 TiB, 4000651739136 bytes, 7813772928 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

(I was expecting to see partitions here, but there seems to be no sda1 or sdb1...)

```
$ cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5]
[raid4] [raid10]  md1 : active raid1 sdb[1] sda[0]
      3906886464 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 0/30 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
```

My friend is going to connect and transfer files to it with WinSCP from his Windows computer.
I still have to install Jellyfin so that he can browse his media easily.

Till here everything is ok!

But as my friend does not know anything about Linux and network as well, I am thinking of an option that could let him access the files on the RAID1 in case of a problem. Like if something prevent him from reaching the server from his Windows computer, if the RAID1 failed somehow or if I am not here to help.

So I ended up installing Linux Mint on a another partition of the SSD, so that he can boot to it in case of emergency, thanks to a dual boot option in Grub.

In order to access his content from Linux Mint, I see two options:

1. re-creating the RAID1
2. allow access to each drive of the RAID1 (/dev/sda and /dev/sdb)

Options 1) should be easily done by activating the RAID1 with `mdadm --assemble --scan` and then mount /dev/md1

I did not try that though, because in case of a RAID problem, I think it should be safer to be able accessing each member of the RAID separately.

That's where I am stuck...

I have tried adding the /dev/sda UUID in fstab

```
/dev/sda 3.7GB  UUID=xxx /mnt/local_disk1 ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
```

and then mount it with `mount /mnt/local_disk1 /dev/sda`, but this is what I get:

```
mount: /mnt/local_disk1 : wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

I also tried to specify the file system with `mount -t ext4 /mnt/local_disk1 /dev/sda`, which gives me:

```
mount: /dev/sda : /mnt/local_disk1 is not a block device
```

Any idea of what I should do to let me access the content of /dev/sda from Linux Mint?
(Obviously without breaking the RAID1 of Ubuntu server ;)

Comment: You access your RAID 1 by mounting the `/dev/md1` as both `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb` are both now part of the metadisk.  `/dev/md1` is what you format and configure.  Since it is a RAID 1, both `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb` are mirrors of each other.

Comment: @Terrance I understand `/dev/md1` is what I format and configure, because of the software RAID1, in Ubuntu Server.
But if I choose to boot on Linux Mint (=Ubuntu 18.04), there is no such RAID1 there, an _fdisk -l_ only shows `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb`, nothing else.

Comment: @Terrance Both OS are installed on an SSD disk, not on the RAID1 array (I should have put the complete result of fdisk). But creating the RAID1 on Ubuntu Server after everything else could indeed be a solution, except I would prefer another option than starting all over again...

Comment: Try mounting `/dev/md1` or `/dev/md1p1` to `/mnt/local_disk1` as I see it in your fdisk layout.  Sorry, I was thinking that you were trying to RAID 1 your OS.  Also, can you edit your question and add the output of `mdadm -S /dev/md1`?

Answer (score -1):

Here under the Linux Mint situation:

```
$ lsblk -o NAME,SIZE,FSTYPE,TYPE,MOUNTPOINT
NAME          SIZE FSTYPE            TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           3.7T linux_raid_member disk 
sdb           3.7T linux_raid_member disk 
nvme0n1     119.2G                   disk 
├─nvme0n1p1   512M vfat              part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2    50G ext4              part 
└─nvme0n1p3  68.8G ext4              part /
```

I finally took option 1) above, recreating the RAID1 in Linux Mint, which should be safer actually.

I only had to

```
$ apt install mdadm
$ reboot
```

And now I have

```
$ lsblk -o NAME,SIZE,FSTYPE,TYPE,MOUNTPOINT
NAME          SIZE FSTYPE            TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda           3.7T linux_raid_member disk  
└─md1         3.7T ext4              raid1 
sdb           3.7T linux_raid_member disk  
└─md1         3.7T ext4              raid1 
nvme0n1     119.2G                   disk  
├─nvme0n1p1   512M vfat              part  /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2    50G ext4              part  
└─nvme0n1p3  68.8G ext4              part  /
```

Just had to mount it and add it to /etc/fstab to let me access the Raid from Linux Mint.  : )

Both OS have identical mdadm.conf and fstab btw.

Comment: Linux mint is not Ubuntu, it is off topic here.